# incremental merge of two files bash+mac

Tags: bash, macos, merge

I want to merge two files row-by-row with the following rules:

*file2* - is the up-to-date english version;
*file1* - previous translated version.

*file1*

```
foo_11: "Марія"
foo_12: "Іванка"
foo_13: "Юлія"
```

*file2*

```
foo_11: "Maria"
foo_112: "Superman"
FOOTLONG: "Subway"
foo_13: "Julia"
```

I want to merge them into result file (*file1*) to look like this

```
foo_11: "Марія"
foo_112: "Superman"
FOOTLONG: "Subway"
foo_13: "Юлія"
```

I.e. if the first part of the row has not changed, the whole row stays. If the first part is changed or does not exist, the whole row should be added or replace the previous version. I want to add to *file1* only rows that are new, and would be good to mark somehow rows that were altered, e.g. *foo_12*.

In other words, I need git-merge but since the files are only partially identical, I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I'm trying to do it in Mac bash.
Thanks

**UPD:** **del**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>`join`, as used in [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071855/45375), is worth considering if the input is already sorted or sorting it on demand *and* outputting the results in sort order is an option.</sup>

An `awk` solution that:

- doesn't require the input files to be sorted,
- preserves the input order of `file2` in the output,
- marks the lines that are exclusive to `file2` with a trailing `*`

```
awk -F':' '
  FNR==NR { seen[$1]=$0; next } 
  $1 in seen { print seen[$1]; next}
  { print $0 "*" }
' file1 file2 # > file1.tmp && mv file1.tmp file1
```

<sup>Remove the `#` to actually update `file1` with the output.</sup>

This stores the `file1` lines in an associative array whose keys are the 1st `:`-based fields first, and then processes `file2` as follows:

- If the 1st field was found in `file1`, output the line from `file1` (the existing translation).
- Otherwise, output the line from `file2` and append a `*` to indicate that the line is new to `file2` (a new line in need of translation).

Comment: @AlCrow: In its current form, the answer only matches lines by everything up to the _first_ `:` (field `$1`). It doesn't matter if the remainder of the line contains additional `:` instances. I'm not sure what you're asking; if your intent is to _expand_ your original requirements, I suggest you create a _new_ question.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now how to track changes in the second part  (after the first `:`)? Now we'll have to use both English versions, I guess. The second part may also contain another `:` in it (inside of the quotes `" "`). And if differences were found in the English files, then the translation has to be updated in the same manner. Thnx

Comment: OK, sorry, I added complexity. I'll create another thread then.

Comment: @AlCrow: Sounds good; I suggest you link to this question from your new question.

Comment: Or maybe I wouldn't need it. Just thought about adding a divider e.g. `;` and then catching changes in two English versions, using your method, then comparing the result file to the translated one. Sounds like anything to you?

Comment: @AlCrow: Honestly, I don't understand what you're proposing, and this comment thread is getting long, so I do think asking a new question is the right approach - feel free to post a link to it here, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The heavy lifting can be done with `join` (which requires the inputs are already sorted):

```
join -a2 file1 file2
```

That gives you:

```
foo_11: "Марія" "Maria"
foo_112: "Superman"
FOOTLONG: "Subway"
foo_13: "Юлія" "Julia"
```

From there it's a simple enough matter to remove the third column:

```
join -a2 file1 file2 | cut -d'"' -f1-3
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, the sorting should stay the same as in the original (in reality it's not sorted).

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next } 
               { print $1, (a[$1]?a[$1]:$2) }
' file1 file2
foo_11: "Марія"
foo_112: "Superman"
FOOTLONG: "Subway"
foo_13: "Юлія"
```